# Log in /connection problems Facebook to Instagram

Tags: facebook, instagram

When I try to log into my Instagram account via Facebook (on a laptop) I keep getting "sorry an unknown error occurred, please try again". I've reset passwords, tried different browsers, cleared caches, etc., and still no connection.
However Instagram does connect to my FB account from my Android phone and has found all my friends to follow, etc.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: If you open the developer tools (F12), and then try to connect - do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: Do you have any ad blocker or privacy guard active on your browser?

Comment: Thanks arieljannai. Following your prompt I disabled my ad-blocker and made my profile public. It has now allowed a log-in.

Comment: Great, glad it helped. I added this solution as an answer.

Comment: Hi Karl, Welcome to WebApps.
Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by
up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough
reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any
question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your
reputation).
Please see the [About] page and also [How do I ask questions
here?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Even though I've tried all the solutions mentioned here, didn't help me. Post log-in with FB account, instagram simply takes me to the sign up page. There is no console error as well but in network tab I could see 302 from FB network calls, how to fix this

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/154313/log-in-with-facebook-takes-to-sign-up-page-of-instagram, this question from 2021 is marked as duplicate even though it's unique problem. Can someone please re-open new question or answer it ?

Answer (score 1):

A lot of times ad blockers and privacy guards block connections from one domain to another.

It might lead to failures in connecting to one service using another.

Try check what the ad blocker / privacy guard has blocked, and also check the console logs. If you see that something related to facebook login/connection was blocked - it's probably the reason.

---

*Written as a helpful answer for others as well, after the issue was resolved by this, in the question comments.*

Comment: I get an Internal Server Error (HTTP 500) from Facebook: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cN0Sd.png

Comment: Even though I've tried all the solutions mentioned here, didn't help me. Post log-in with FB account, instagram simply takes me to the sign up page. There is no console error as well but in network tab I could see 302 from FB network calls, how to fix this

Answer (score 0):

This only works (currently) with Instagram Business profiles. Creator accounts don't give any errors sensible errors, just "Sorry, an unknown error occurred. Please try again."